# Combine 2 columns which are having comma separated strings into 1 column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A","a$b,c$d,k$m","h,y,a"], ["B","n$e,d$w,t$y","t,r,s"]], columns=["id","c1","c2"])
```

I want to combine each element of column c1 which are separated by a comma with another element of column c2 with an asterisk(*)

Expected output:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([["A","a$b*h,c$d*y,k$m*a"], ["B","n$e*t,d$w*r,t$y*s"]], columns=["id","c3"])
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract values and `zip`, for add `*` is used `f-string`s and last join in `join`:

```
df['c3'] = [','.join(f'{i}*{j}' for i, j in zip(x.split(','), y.split(',')))
                                for x, y in zip(df.pop('c1'), df.pop('c2'))]
print (df)
  id                 c3
0  A  a$b*h,c$d*y,k$m*a
1  B  n$e*t,d$w*r,t$y*s
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try out the below code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A","a$b,c$d,k$m","h,y,a"], ["B","n$e,d$w,t$y","t,r,s"]], columns=["id","c1","c2"])

def combine_list(a, b):
          return (',').join([i+'*'+j for i, j in zip(a, b)])
        
df['c3'] = df.apply(lambda x: combine_list(x['c1'].split(','), x['c2'].split(',')), axis=1)
df_out = df[["id", "c3"]]
```

Hope this solves your query!